# Text is going up/down? Not across. Javascript Loop.

Tags: javascript, loops, text, iteration

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var namIn = window.prompt("Enter Senator’s State and FULL Name, separated by space:" );
var namAr = namIn.split("");
var namArLen = namAr.length;

document.write( namAr + "<br>" + "Length:" + namArLen);
var i;
for (i = namArLen-1; i >=0;i--)
{var result = document.write("<br>" + "<h1>" + namAr[i] + "</h1>" ); }
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I used a loop to help reverse my text (done for an into to JS assginment) but the letters are going in a straight line up and down. Like:
O
L
L
E
H
(It's supposed to be a senator's name, but "hello" will do for an example)
Why is this and how can I make it look normal?

Comment: You can use another var to store the (building) chars, and then print them out all at once. That will work. See my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it look normal by putting the letters into another variable and then writing that variable out all at once. Look at lines 6, 9 and 11 in this (tested) solution.

```
<script>
var namIn = window.prompt("Enter Senator’s State and FULL Name, separated by space:" );
var namAr = namIn.split("");
var namArLen = namAr.length;

document.write( namAr + "<br>" + "Length:" + namArLen);
var result =  '';
var i;
for (i = namArLen-1; i >=0;i--) {
    result = result + namAr[i];
}
document.write("<br>" + "<h1>" + result + "</h1>" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using H1 tags which create new lines

```
{var result = document.write( namAr[i]  ); }
```

use a style to increase the font size

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/rk6Nk/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should add one css rule, for example:

```
h1 {display: inline-block;}
```

And remove all of BR tags.